# Angular2 - Dynamically add selector in template

Tags: angular

I would like to dynamically build selector or call component in the template with a property.
Like in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LDknl7iu2UwowBcGqxi?p=preview).

Example :

```
<!-- What I want to do -->
<frame-{{type}}></frame-{{type}}>

<!-- Or -->
<frame [type]="{{type}}"></frame>
```

Is there a workaround for this or is it not possible with angular2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's at least currently not supported. Components and directives are only applied to static HTML.

You can use <strike>[DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)</strike> [ViewContainerRef.createComponent](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#createComponent-anchor) to imperatively add/remove comonents.

Comment: For information,
how to use it : http://plnkr.co/edit/txdW7zCFL7fADIuvpiip?p=preview

Comment: Is this feature still not supported in angular 2?

Comment: No, and unlikely it ever will.

Comment: @Zysce your plunker is deprecated. :(

Comment: The RC.7 Plunker in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 works and the code should still be the same even in Angular 4

Comment: You can also have a look at https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/2896/files (just merged). I haven't found it on http://angular.io yet (should appear soon).

Comment: Thanks figured it out using your solution stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Will check that file.